# Rewrite Rule Adds ? to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic-url

I'm trying to redirect all URLs to `https` except ones that start with `/feeds/`. This is an ExpressionEngine site, so I also have to remove `index.php` from the beginning of the URLs. The hosting setup also requires that `?` be at the end of `index.php`. Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL for everything but feeds
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php\?*/)*feeds/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [R,L]

# Remove index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But when I go to `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog`, it gets redirected to `https://www.mysite.com/?/feeds/blog`.

I don't understand why this is happening. Here's the course of events as I see it:

1. `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog` is using port 80, so it meets the first condition
2. `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog` starts with `/feeds/`, so it fails the next condition and exits the rule
3. `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog` is not a file or directory, so it meets the next 2 conditions.
4. `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog` is changed to `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog` and loops back to the top.
5. `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog` is using port 80 and it starts with `/index.php?/feeds/`, so it fails the condition again and exits the rule
6. `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog` does exist, so it fails the next 2 conditions and exits the rule.
7. The final server-side URL is `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog`, and the client-side URL is still `http://www.mysite.com/feeds/blog`.

What's happening here? Where's that `?` segment coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this corrected code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL for everything but feeds
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feeds/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L,NE]

# Remove index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you please explain the changes you made and why they should work?

Comment: Well to start with you're capturing `$1` but using `$2` then in 2nd rule you're using `.*` instead of `.+`

Comment: I get why you changed `$2` to `$1`, but not why you changed `.+` to `.*`.

Comment: First of all I think you should test and see if it really works for you. I can answer all of your questions if this works :)

Comment: Tested. `http://mysite.com/feeds/blog` is redirected to `https://mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog`.

Comment: Bad result for a couple of reasons. First, it redirected to HTTPS when it shouldn't have. Second, `index.php?` is displaying on the client-side. The final client-side URL should be `http://mysite.com/feeds/blog`, and the final server-side url should be `http://mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog`. This says to me that the updated URL from the second rule (`http://mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/blog`) is passing the first HTTPS conditions when it shouldn't.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feeds/`?

Comment: Thanks, yes it should be, my mistake. Corrected, try it now.

Comment: And what URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere in your system AND is there any other code in this .htaccess file?

Comment: No, there isn't any other .htaccess and there isn't any other code in the .htaccess file.

Comment: But if there is a blog directory under `/feeds` then there must be some .htaccess also?

Comment: Those aren't real directories, but dynamic ExpressionEngine URL segments.

Comment: No. `http://mysite.com/feeds/abc` is redirected to `https://mysite.com/index.php?/feeds/abc` in the browser.